# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.7:javadoc (default) on project oozie-client

Tags: maven, oozie

While building Apache Oozie, the below error occured.

export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=4096m"
./bin/mkdistro.sh -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2 -DskipTests -Puber  -Phadoop-2 -Dhadoop.version=2.7.1 -Dhive.version=1.2.1 -Dspark.version=1.6.2

```
[INFO] The goal 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.7:javadoc' has not be previously called for the project: 'org.apache.oozie:oozie-zookeeper-security-tests:jar:4.2.0'. Trying to invoke it...
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=4096m; support was removed in 8.0
[ERROR] Error fetching link: /home1/oozie-4.2.0/hadooplibs/hadoop-distcp-2/target/site/apidocs/package-list. Ignored it.
[ERROR] Error fetching link: /home1/oozie-4.2.0/hadooplibs/hadoop-auth-2/target/site/apidocs/package-list. Ignored it.
[ERROR] Error fetching link: /home1/oozie-4.2.0/sharelib/spark/target/site/apidocs/package-list. Ignored it.
[ERROR] Error fetching link: /home1/oozie-4.2.0/webapp/target/site/apidocs/package-list. Ignored it.
[ERROR] Error fetching link: /home1/oozie-4.2.0/minitest/target/site/apidocs/package-list. Ignored it.
[ERROR] Error fetching link: /home1/oozie-4.2.0/distro/target/site/apidocs/package-list. Ignored it.
[ERROR] Error fetching link: /home1/oozie-4.2.0/zookeeper-security-tests/target/site/apidocs/package-list. Ignored it.
[INFO]
56 errors
85 warnings
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Main ................................. SUCCESS [6:33.229s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Utils hadoop-2-4.2.0 .......... SUCCESS [1:14.085s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Distcp hadoop-2-4.2.0 ......... SUCCESS [0.778s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Auth hadoop-2-4.2.0 Test ...... SUCCESS [0.758s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Hadoop Libs .......................... SUCCESS [0.058s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Client ............................... FAILURE [6:02.532s]
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Oozie ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib HCatalog ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Distcp ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Core ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Streaming .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Pig ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Hive ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Hive 2 ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Sqoop ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Examples ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Spark ...................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Docs ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie WebApp ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Tools ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie MiniOozie ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie Distro ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Apache Oozie ZooKeeper Security Tests ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 17:00.267s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jan 13 18:53:21 KST 2021
[INFO] Final Memory: 59M/1008M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-javadoc-plugin:2.7:javadoc (default) on project oozie-client: An error has occurred in JavaDocs report generation:
[ERROR] Exit code: 1 - /home1/oozie-4.2.0/client/src/main/java/org/apache/oozie/cli/CLIParser.java:67: warning: no description for @param
[ERROR] * @param hasArguments
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /home1/oozie-4.2.0/client/src/main/java/org/apache/oozie/cli/OozieCLI.java:216: error: self-closing element not allowed
[ERROR] * <p/>
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /home1/oozie-4.2.0/client/src/main/java/org/apache/oozie/cli/OozieCLI.java:523: warning: no @param for jobType
[ERROR] protected Options createScriptLanguageOptions(String jobType) {
[ERROR] ^
[ERROR] /home1/oozie-4.2.0/client/src/main/java/org/apache/oozie/cli/OozieCLI.java:599: error: self-closing element not allowed
[ERROR] * <p/>
[ERROR] ^
```

What I tried is to edit `pom.xml` file, from

```
1502                     <configuration>
1503                             <additionalparam>${maven.javadoc.opts}</additionalparam>
1504                     </configuration>
```

to

```
1502                     <configuration>
1503                             <doclint>none</doclint>
1504                     </configuration>
```

But this didn't work.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to the [javadoc:javadoc](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html), property named [failOnError](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html#failOnError)

> Specifies if the build will fail if there are errors during javadoc execution or not.
>
> Default value is: true.

This causes the build failed when there is any error during creating javadoc.

To ignore this we may config the plugin as the following: -

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${some-version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <failOnError>false</failOnError>
        ...
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```